# Optimizing date range search on large table

Tags: mysql, openfire

I have a table of chat messages which has grown to >4m rows.

I need to get messages sent to and from a user within a certain date range.

At first this query was ok but with the current size of the table it's taking way too long (>10s).

I have tried creating many combinations of indexes; MySQL is using a composite index on messageType+sentDate

```
SELECT `ofMessageArchive`.*
FROM `ofMessageArchive`
WHERE `ofMessageArchive`.`messageType` IN ('Message')
AND (ofMessageArchive.fromJID = 'user@example.com' OR ofMessageArchive.toJID = 'user@example.com')
AND (ofMessageArchive.sentDate > '1462235333109') 
ORDER BY ofMessageArchive.sentDate ASC LIMIT 50
```

Any ideas how I can optimize this query?

[EDIT] `EXPLAIN` result:

```
+----+-------------+------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                                       | key                    | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ofMessageArchive | ref  | index_ofMessageArchive_on_fromJID_and_toJID,index_ofMessageArchive_on_sentDate,index_ofMessageArchive_on_messageType,idxMessageTypeSentDate,ofMessageArchive_fromjid_idx,ofMessageArchive_tojid_idx | idxMessageTypeSentDate | 767     | const | 731570 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN` result of this query

Comment: Added explain result

Answer (score 0):

You ran into the problem of treating outgoing messages differently to incoming messages (basically a normalization problem), so you cannot use an index on the username directly, which is probably your most significant value.

If you don't have them yet, create the indexes `ofMessageArchive(fromJID, messageType, sentDate)` and
`ofMessageArchive(toJID, messageType, sentDate)` (maybe in a different order, depending on how many different values you have for each of these columns and what other querys you use, but start with this order).

To use these indexes, use `union`:

```
select * from     
( (SELECT `ofMessageArchive`.*
   FROM `ofMessageArchive`
   WHERE (ofMessageArchive.fromJID = 'user@example.com')
   AND `ofMessageArchive`.`messageType` IN ('Message')
   AND (ofMessageArchive.sentDate > '1462235333109') 
   ORDER BY ofMessageArchive.sentDate ASC LIMIT 50
  ) union
  (SELECT `ofMessageArchive`.*
   FROM `ofMessageArchive`
   WHERE (ofMessageArchive.toJID = 'user@example.com')
   AND `ofMessageArchive`.`messageType` IN ('Message')
   AND (ofMessageArchive.sentDate > '1462235333109') 
   ORDER BY ofMessageArchive.sentDate ASC LIMIT 50
  )
) s
order by s.sentDate ASC LIMIT 50
```